# meta_query is not allowing to show posts when querying multiple arguments in a WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I am trying to show daily birthdays in a school website. There are different portions for teacher's and student's birthdays. I want to query only teacher's birthdays. My custom fields are Position (Teacher or student - select input), date of birth (date picker). My code looks like this:

```
<?php
$today = date('d/m');
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'birthday',
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'meta_query' => array(
     array(
     'key' => 'field_position',
     'value' => 'Teacher'
     )
     array(
     'key' => 'field_dob',
     'value'=> $today
 )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<?php if($the_query->have_posts()) : while($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post(); ?>
   <?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: i think you can check `$today`  variable in value get or not? otherwise your code is done. AND also check post-type name and key-name is perfect or not?

Comment: Post type name and key names are perfect. Even $today prints exactly what my date of birth field prints. for example: In one of my posts I have set the date of birth as today's day and month and it prints in the same format as the $today variable prints.

Comment: `'type' => 'DATE',` pass in `meta_query` in second array because default compare is =. More info : https://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/

Comment: Tried it. Still not working.

Comment: Another weird thing is happening, when I remove the meta_query and just query all posts from birthday, its spitting out the posts but when meta_query is added it does not show any post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<?php
$date_today = time();
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'birthday',
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'meta_query' => array(
                      'relation'  =>   'AND',
                      array(
                         'key' => 'field_position',
                         'value' => 'Teacher'
                         ),
                      array(
                          'key' => 'field_dob',
                          'value' => $date_today,
                          'compare' => '=',
                          )

                     )
                    );    

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);


if($the_query->have_posts()) : while($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post(); 

the_title(); 

endwhile; 

endif; 

?>
```

Comment: No. I want to get posts from 'birthday' custom post type who have the position as 'Teacher' and date and month of birth matches the current day's day and month

Comment: nothing happened

Comment: what is the format of the date for field_dob

Comment: I used date and month only......coz to get the birthday only date and month is required so I set it as d/m